# Check if a nested array contains any element of another nested array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, search

I have 2 nested array and I want to check if id's from the `list1` and if there are same id in the `list2` add that object of the `list2` + `tag` and `count` from the `list1` to a new array.New array has the `tag`,`count` and the list of details of id that is in the `list1` and is same as id in the `list2`

Note: these 2 lists doesn't have the same size

Thank in advance for help

For example:

**list1**

```
const list1 = [
    {
        "id": [
            "5cca1dbc-dd5c-498f-8f83-735062c05240",
            "2a10c30a-7c3a-4081-8246-9d37e19c2d6f",
            "3128f36c-1c79-4301-b08f-e0182c256c03"
        ],
        "tag": "tag1",
        "count": {
            "low": 53,
            "high": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "id": [
            "510019af-1728-4628-9019-343cd3c1b3e1",
            "fb420746-4d11-4d2e-ab7f-b8a73e5b8f8e",
            "adf0cd4c-3072-4ecf-9aa7-ecd5580c31ae"
        ],
        "tag": "tag2",
        "count": {
            "low": 43,
            "high": 0
        }
    }
]
```

**list2**

```
[
    {
        "id": "5cca1dbc-dd5c-498f-8f83-735062c05240",
        "createdDate": "2017-10-08T22:40:33.020Z",
        "modifiedDate": "2017-10-08T22:40:33.020Z",
        "title": "Good morning! #tag1",
        "text": " ",
        "media": [
            {
                "id": "1f8c564c-91f1-457c-b4c1-0820c03861b4",
                        "metadata": {
                            "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
                            "imageHeight": 400,
                            "imageWidth": 300
                        }
            }
        ],
        "topics": [
            {
                "topicId": "22a96a83-def3-4981-bc91-9277464b7105"
            },
            {
                "name": "Fashion",
                "topicId": "6d4caea2-8387-42f3-977d-06a4bb063c44"
            }
        ],
        "language": null,
        "sourceId": "d25205ca-2ef308261113",
    },
    {
        "id": "fb420746-4d11-4d2e-ab7f-b8a73e5b8f8e",
        "createdDate": "2017-10-08T22:40:33.020Z",
        "modifiedDate": "2017-10-08T22:40:33.020Z",
        "title": "Good morning! #tag1",
        "text": " ",
        "media": [
            {
                "id": "1f8c564c-91f1-457c-b4c1-0820c03861b4",
                        "metadata": {
                            "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
                            "imageHeight": 400,
                            "imageWidth": 300
                        }
            }
        ],
        "topics": [
            {
                "topicId": "22a96a83-def3-4981-bc91-9277464b7105"
            },
            {
                "name": "Fashion",
                "topicId": "6d4caea2-8387-42f3-977d-06a4bb063c44"
            }
        ],
        "language": null,
        "sourceId": "d25205ca-2ef308261113",
    },
    {
        "id": "efde2bc9-018b-49c1-9c01-a4eda9817a33",
        "createdDate": "2017-10-08T22:40:33.020Z",
        "modifiedDate": "2017-10-08T22:40:33.020Z",
        "title": "Good morning! #tag1",
        "text": " ",
        "media": [
            {
                "id": "1f8c564c-91f1-457c-b4c1-0820c03861b4",
                        "metadata": {
                            "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
                            "imageHeight": 400,
                            "imageWidth": 300
                        }
            }
        ],
        "topics": [
            {
                "topicId": "22a96a83-def3-4981-bc91-9277464b7105"
            },
            {
                "name": "Fashion",
                "topicId": "6d4caea2-8387-42f3-977d-06a4bb063c44"
            }
        ],
        "language": null,
        "sourceId": "d25205ca-2ef308261113",
    }
]
```

**new array**

```
 [
{
    "tag": "tag1",
    "count": {
        "low": 53,
        "high": 0
    },
    "details": [
               {
        "id": "5cca1dbc-dd5c-498f-8f83-735062c05240",
        "createdDate": "2017-10-08T22:40:33.020Z",
        "modifiedDate": "2017-10-08T22:40:33.020Z",
        "title": "Good morning! #tag1",
        "text": " ",
        "media": [
            {
                "id": "1f8c564c-91f1-457c-b4c1-0820c03861b4",
                        "metadata": {
                            "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
                            "imageHeight": 400,
                            "imageWidth": 300
                        }
            }
        ],
        "topics": [
            {
                "topicId": "22a96a83-def3-4981-bc91-9277464b7105"
            },
            {
                "name": "Fashion",
                "topicId": "6d4caea2-8387-42f3-977d-06a4bb063c44"
            }
        ],
        "language": null,
        "sourceId": "d25205ca-2ef308261113",
    }
 ]
}
]
```

Comment: can you post the list2 as proper , it has some error on the brackets. List1 is fine

Comment: I want to search from the `id` list of the `list1` and if there is any same `id` in the `list2`, grab those info from the `list2` like: id `"5cca1dbc-dd5c-498f-8f83-735062c05240"` is in the list id in the `list1`, so there is same `id` in the `list2` as well, so I'll add the `tag`,`count` ,and the details of this id into the new list

Comment: can you post the list2 as same like list1, some brackets missing is there on the list2. It will be helpful to the post the solution with the the given data

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS THOMAS Updated

Comment: Please check the solution and let me know whether it worked for you.

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS Thank you for the response, it should work as you show but it didn't work for me

Comment: @H77 Thank you for your answer But it didn't work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much for your responses,
I could solve it that day by this:

```
const responseValueList = {};
  const hashtagsList = [];

  for (const responseRow of list1) {
    const obj = {};
    obj.hashtagName = responseRow.hashtag;
    obj.hashtagCount = responseRow.count;
    const rateableList = []
    for (const responseSectionTwo of list2) {
      if (responseRow.id.includes(responseSectionTwo.id)) {
        rateableList.push(responseSectionTwo);
      }
    }
    obj.hashtagItems = rateableList;
    hashtagsList.push(obj);
  }
```

Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through `list1`, check if the `id` exists in `list2` and if it does add it to a new array.

e.g.

```
var result = [];

for (let item of list1) {
  let details = list2.filter(l2 => item.id.includes(l2.id));
  if (details.length > 0) {
    result.push({
      tag: item.tag,
      count: item.count,
      details: details
    });
  }
}
```

If you want *all* items in `list1` to show up regardless of the `id` existing in `list2` you could use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and return a new object for each item in `list1`.

```
var result = list1.map(l1 => {
  return {
    tag: l1.tag,
    count: l1.count,
    details: list2.filter(l2 => l1.id.includes(l2.id))
  };
});
```

```js
const list1 = [{
    "id": [
      "5cca1dbc-dd5c-498f-8f83-735062c05240",
      "2a10c30a-7c3a-4081-8246-9d37e19c2d6f",
      "3128f36c-1c79-4301-b08f-e0182c256c03"
    ],
    "tag": "tag1",
    "count": {
      "low": 53,
      "high": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "id": [
      "510019af-1728-4628-9019-343cd3c1b3e1",
      "fb420746-4d11-4d2e-ab7f-b8a73e5b8f8e",
      "adf0cd4c-3072-4ecf-9aa7-ecd5580c31ae"
    ],
    "tag": "tag2",
    "count": {
      "low": 43,
      "high": 0
    }
  }
];

const list2 = [{
    "id": "5cca1dbc-dd5c-498f-8f83-735062c05240",
    "createdDate": "2017-10-08T22:40:33.020Z",
    "modifiedDate": "2017-10-08T22:40:33.020Z",
    "title": "Good morning! #tag1",
    "text": " ",
    "media": [{
      "id": "1f8c564c-91f1-457c-b4c1-0820c03861b4",
      "metadata": {
        "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
        "imageHeight": 400,
        "imageWidth": 300
      }
    }],
    "topics": [{
        "topicId": "22a96a83-def3-4981-bc91-9277464b7105"
      },
      {
        "name": "Fashion",
        "topicId": "6d4caea2-8387-42f3-977d-06a4bb063c44"
      }
    ],
    "language": null,
    "sourceId": "d25205ca-2ef308261113",
  },
  {
    "id": "fb420746-4d11-4d2e-ab7f-b8a73e5b8f8e",
    "createdDate": "2017-10-08T22:40:33.020Z",
    "modifiedDate": "2017-10-08T22:40:33.020Z",
    "title": "Good morning! #tag1",
    "text": " ",
    "media": [{
      "id": "1f8c564c-91f1-457c-b4c1-0820c03861b4",
      "metadata": {
        "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
        "imageHeight": 400,
        "imageWidth": 300
      }
    }],
    "topics": [{
        "topicId": "22a96a83-def3-4981-bc91-9277464b7105"
      },
      {
        "name": "Fashion",
        "topicId": "6d4caea2-8387-42f3-977d-06a4bb063c44"
      }
    ],
    "language": null,
    "sourceId": "d25205ca-2ef308261113",
  },
  {
    "id": "efde2bc9-018b-49c1-9c01-a4eda9817a33",
    "createdDate": "2017-10-08T22:40:33.020Z",
    "modifiedDate": "2017-10-08T22:40:33.020Z",
    "title": "Good morning! #tag1",
    "text": " ",
    "media": [{
      "id": "1f8c564c-91f1-457c-b4c1-0820c03861b4",
      "metadata": {
        "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
        "imageHeight": 400,
        "imageWidth": 300
      }
    }],
    "topics": [{
        "topicId": "22a96a83-def3-4981-bc91-9277464b7105"
      },
      {
        "name": "Fashion",
        "topicId": "6d4caea2-8387-42f3-977d-06a4bb063c44"
      }
    ],
    "language": null,
    "sourceId": "d25205ca-2ef308261113",
  }
];

var result1 = [];

for (let item of list1) {
  let details = list2.filter(l2 => item.id.includes(l2.id));
  if (details.length > 0) {
    result1.push({
      tag: item.tag,
      count: item.count,
      details: details
    });
  }
}

console.log(result1);

var result2 = list1.map(l1 => {
  return {
    tag: l1.tag,
    count: l1.count,
    details: list2.filter(l2 => l1.id.includes(l2.id))
  };
});

console.log(result2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach),

First you need to take list1 and loop through each item, inside each item you have property called id, which is again a collection of array. you need to do a foreach with the id and check with the list2 and once the list2.id matches with the id of list 1 . it should push an object of your required output.

I hope the below code will solve the issue.

```js
const list1 = [
    {
        "id": [
            "5cca1dbc-dd5c-498f-8f83-735062c05240",
            "2a10c30a-7c3a-4081-8246-9d37e19c2d6f",
            "3128f36c-1c79-4301-b08f-e0182c256c03"
        ],
        "tag": "tag1",
        "count": {
            "low": 53,
            "high": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "id": [
            "510019af-1728-4628-9019-343cd3c1b3e1",
            "fb420746-4d11-4d2e-ab7f-b8a73e5b8f8e",
            "adf0cd4c-3072-4ecf-9aa7-ecd5580c31ae"
        ],
        "tag": "tag2",
        "count": {
            "low": 43,
            "high": 0
        }
    }
]

const list2 = [
    {
        "id": "5cca1dbc-dd5c-498f-8f83-735062c05240",
        "createdDate": "2017-10-08T22:40:33.020Z",
        "modifiedDate": "2017-10-08T22:40:33.020Z",
        "title": "Good morning! #tag1",
        "text": " ",
        "media": [
            {
                "id": "1f8c564c-91f1-457c-b4c1-0820c03861b4",
                        "metadata": {
                            "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
                            "imageHeight": 400,
                            "imageWidth": 300
                        }
            }
        ],
        "topics": [
            {
                "topicId": "22a96a83-def3-4981-bc91-9277464b7105"
            },
            {
                "name": "Fashion",
                "topicId": "6d4caea2-8387-42f3-977d-06a4bb063c44"
            }
        ],
        "language": null,
        "sourceId": "d25205ca-2ef308261113",
    },
    {
        "id": "fb420746-4d11-4d2e-ab7f-b8a73e5b8f8e",
        "createdDate": "2017-10-08T22:40:33.020Z",
        "modifiedDate": "2017-10-08T22:40:33.020Z",
        "title": "Good morning! #tag1",
        "text": " ",
        "media": [
            {
                "id": "1f8c564c-91f1-457c-b4c1-0820c03861b4",
                        "metadata": {
                            "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
                            "imageHeight": 400,
                            "imageWidth": 300
                        }
            }
        ],
        "topics": [
            {
                "topicId": "22a96a83-def3-4981-bc91-9277464b7105"
            },
            {
                "name": "Fashion",
                "topicId": "6d4caea2-8387-42f3-977d-06a4bb063c44"
            }
        ],
        "language": null,
        "sourceId": "d25205ca-2ef308261113",
    },
    {
        "id": "efde2bc9-018b-49c1-9c01-a4eda9817a33",
        "createdDate": "2017-10-08T22:40:33.020Z",
        "modifiedDate": "2017-10-08T22:40:33.020Z",
        "title": "Good morning! #tag1",
        "text": " ",
        "media": [
            {
                "id": "1f8c564c-91f1-457c-b4c1-0820c03861b4",
                        "metadata": {
                            "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
                            "imageHeight": 400,
                            "imageWidth": 300
                        }
            }
        ],
        "topics": [
            {
                "topicId": "22a96a83-def3-4981-bc91-9277464b7105"
            },
            {
                "name": "Fashion",
                "topicId": "6d4caea2-8387-42f3-977d-06a4bb063c44"
            }
        ],
        "language": null,
        "sourceId": "d25205ca-2ef308261113",
    }
]

var arr = []
list1.forEach(l1I => {
 l1I.id.forEach(eID => list2.forEach(l2I => {
   if(l2I.id === eID){
    var obj = {}
      obj["details"] = l2I;
      obj["tag"] = l1I.tag;
      obj["count"] = l1I.count;
      arr.push(obj);
   } 
}))
})


console.log("output", arr)
```